# fullpage.js: disable page scroll when scrolled with the mouse pointer inside a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

**What's happening:** Scrolling works no matter which position i have the mouse while i scroll.

**What i want to achieve:** When the user scrolls with the mouse pointer positioned inside a particular container, I would like to disable the plugin from changing pages. When the user scrolls with the mouse pointer outside that same container, the normal functionality of the plugin should be restored; i.e. the pages should be scrollable again.

**What have i tried:** I listened for the scroll event on the document and found out whether the mouse is inside the container while executing the scroll and store the possibilities as a boolean.

```
$(document).bind("mousewheel", function(event) {
   // preventScroll = true;
   console.log(event);
   if($(event.target).closest(".no-scroll").length) {             
     preventScroll = true;
    }
    else {
      preventScroll = false;
    }
});
```

Then `onLeave` i try to find out the value of preventScroll and try to stop event propagation (since in want to stop an actual event) by returning `false`

```
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(preventScroll);
      if(preventScroll) {
        console.log("no-scroll")
        return false;
      }
  }, 10);
```

I an using `setTimeout` to capture the desired value of `preventScroll` although I guess the plugin executes a scroll within that `10 ms` and that's why `return false` doesn't seem to have an effect. I can't seem to figure out how else to proceed to achieve the desired functionality.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/binarytrance/pen/YxBqPj

In this implementation, the container i want to disable scroll is in the second page/section. Please be aware of the values spit out in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fullpage.js option `normalScrollElements`. Check the fullpage.js docs for more info:

> **normalScrollElements:** (default null) If you want to avoid the auto scroll when scrolling over some elements, this is the option you need to use. (useful for maps, scrolling divs etc.) It requires a string with the jQuery selectors for those elements. (For example: normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2'). This option should not be applied to any section/slide element itself.