# disable fullpage.js when mouse inside a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js, mousewheel

Basically the WordPress theme I'm using is using fullpage.js .

Now, I manually create a scroll-box div inside the page. **How can I disable fullpage scroll when my mouse is inside that scroll-box div so that it works like normal?**

I found this [fullpage.js: disable page scroll when scrolled with the mouse pointer inside a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995419/fullpage-js-disable-page-scroll-when-scrolled-with-the-mouse-pointer-inside-a-c) but I've no idea how to properly set it to the `.scroll-box`

```css
.scroll-box {
    width: auto;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-box">
<p style="font-weight: bold;">Industry:
Business, Finance</p>
<p style="font-weight: bold;">Objective:
User acquisition, User engagement</p>
<p style="font-weight: bold;">Services provided:
Performance Marketing, Design</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et odio purus. In volutpat, nisi ac malesuada volutpat, nisl magna vehicula leo, et posuere nunc nunc in nisl. Etiam facilisis convallis luctus. Aliquam nec luctus libero. Ut tincidunt ut massa sed malesuada. Aenean dolor orci, laoreet a imperdiet id, maximus id elit. Ut consequat tortor ac dui sollicitudin, non lacinia ante feugiat. Integer in orci sem. Nam tempus libero in enim efficitur dapibus. Nunc consequat lacinia libero quis convallis. Nunc vulputate interdum diam eget cursus.

Maecenas purus nisi, sodales quis turpis nec, luctus fringilla leo. Integer dapibus interdum risus nec tincidunt. Morbi pretium sit amet mi quis ullamcorper. Integer tempus hendrerit enim, aliquet finibus dolor molestie sed. Donec ac eleifend diam, at gravida eros. Mauris malesuada dolor at magna facilisis finibus. Vivamus fringilla nisi non sapien vestibulum scelerisque in vel libero. Sed mattis rhoncus pulvinar. Suspendisse quam urna, hendrerit quis libero quis, maximus laoreet sem. Maecenas vestibulum massa in mattis rutrum. Proin eu finibus nibh. Mauris quis nibh sit amet nibh posuere pulvinar quis ac massa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector syntax when you have access to where `new fullpage()` is being called:

```js
  const fullpage = new fullpage('#fullpagediv', { normalScrollElements: '.scroll-box' })
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Meaning I need to find the source file of this fullPage.js first?